# Options for executing SQL commands in parallel

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, etl

**Scenario**

Note: I am using SQL Server 2017 Enterprise

I am looping through a list of databases and copying data to them out of one database. This database will only be accessed by the script (no other transactions will be made against it from something else). The copy includes copying straight table to table, or will have more complex, longer-running queries or stored procedures. All of this is done with SQL Server jobs calling procedures; I'm not using anything like SSIS.

[image]

**Question**

Instead of looping through all the databases and running the statements one at a time, I want to be able to run them in parallel. Is there an easy way to do this?

Options I've thought of:

- Run each data transfer as a job and then run all the jobs at once. From my understanding, they would be executed asynchronously, but I'm not 100% sure.
- Generate the SQL statements and write a script outside of SQL Server (e.g. Powershell or Python) and run all the commands in parallel
- Leverage SSIS
  I prefer not to do this, since this would take too much work and I'm not very familiar with it. This may be used down the road though.

Comment: I would take a look at [Database Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data) or external Tables where you would manage the job on the target database instead of the source. Furthermore take a look at azCopy which would be tasked on OS level.

Comment: There are few more ways beside of the three you mentioned already listed in this thread: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/173265/run-stored-procedures-in-parallel. If the requirement is to stick to T-SQL, perhaps the **Service Broker** is an option to use, though it is a slightly complicated feature.

Comment: meq, I don't think I'll be able to leverage a database sync. I have to extract specific data out of the first database that is relevant to the database it's going into and the database schemas will be different on all databases

Alexander, that is helpful. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to do *X* amount of things at the same time, you'll need to use multiple batches. Of course, depending on what you're doing, and version of SQL Server, you may then suffer dead locks, or have to wait for the index usage, etc. You won't be able to use a single state the do multiple batches

Comment: Larnu, it would be pretty straight-forward to split everything into multiple batches. I'm not sure what to use to execute those batches though. 

Also, I am on SQL Server 2017 Enterprise

Comment: Replication might be a good option. However, to get a helpful answer, you may want to explain what you don't like in your existing data transfer solution. Assuming it exists, of course.

Comment: Are all of the databases on separate servers? It probably doesn't make sense to try to use parallel operations on a single server, especially if they databases also share storage devices.

Answer (score 0):

Use powershell...

Create a table on the central database to house instance / connection string details. (Remember to obfuscate for security)
Create another table to house the queries. 
Create a third table to map Instance to Query.

In powershell create a collection / list based object. Deserialized from your data entries. The object will be made up of three properties {Source / Destination / Query}

Write a method / function to carry out the ETL based work. CONNECT TO DB, READ FROM SOURCE, WRITE TO DEST.

Iterate over the collection using Foreach-Parallel construct with your function nested within. This will initiate a new SPID based on the number of elements in the collection and pass those values into your function where the work will be carried out.

Comment: Some things to consider, make sure the user your client uses to connect to those source dbs exists on those source dbs and has limited rights.